# Javascript - typeof in a ternary

Tags: javascript, undefined, ternary-operator, typechecking

I am trying type check for undefined in the first part of a ternary

```
   return typeof this.scores != 'undefined' ? this.scores.filter()
```

and

```
   return (typeof this.scores != 'undefined') ? this.scores.filter()
```

Do I have to use a full if/else?

Comment: where is the `:` part?

Answer (score 4):

What you have will work if you finish the ternary expression:

```
return typeof this.scores != 'undefined' ? this.scores.filter() : null;
```

You can replace `null` with whatever value you want to return instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could return an `undefined` or the value of the function call by using a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) instead of a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) without an else part (which is not possible).

```
return this.scores && this.scores.filter();
```

Comment: Without knowing what value the `else` will be returned, this answer is not yet confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking of the problem step wise in the following manner:

```
this.scores != 'undefined'
```

Is an expression which returns true if `this.scores` is any other value than `undefined`

Let's say `this.scores` is not undefined, now we are left with the following:

```
return true ? this.scores.filter()
```

This would not be valid JS because a ternary expression **needs** to have a true and false case separated with a colon. We can fix this in the following manner without an if else statement:

```
return true ? this.scores.filter() : null
```

Remember the ternary **expression** is (of course) an **expression**, which means that it returns a value. this value then in turn can be returned by the `return` statement you already have in the beginning.

To conclude, no `if else` statement is needed when you complete your ternary expression.